# How can i convert this JSON to Java Object?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm learning JACKSON. To train my skills i want to get field "URL" from following JSON:
[image: 1]

How can i do that? I don't need whole JSON-object, just one field (URL).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the JSON into a Java Object for that you will need to define POJOS.
Maybe this will help :-

```
final ObjectNode yourNode = new ObjectMapper().readValue(<Your_JSON_Input_String>, ObjectNode.class);
if (node.has("URL")) {
    System.out.println("URL :- " + node.get("URL"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonString = "{\"data\":[{\"url\":\"http://example.com\"}]}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString); // 1

        JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data"); // 2

        JSONObject objectAtIndex0 = data.getJSONObject(0); // 3

        String urlAtObject0 = objectAtIndex0.getString("url"); // 4

        System.out.println(urlAtObject0);
    }
}
```

1. Get JSON object for whole JSON string
2. Get `data` as JSON array
3. Get JSON object at desired index or loop on JSON array of previous step
4. Get `url` field of the JSON object